# How to remove adsense codes from whole site

Tags: regex

I have a thousand html pages (without admin panel) with codes of adsense.
And I want to remove all of them from html.
One code looks like:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7165746718333100"
 data-ad-slot="9087512399"></ins>
```

Another:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-7163746711373100"
 data-ad-slot="7467236139"></ins>
```

All of them are similar but not equal. A tried to write regex to find and replace it with empty string, but unsuccessfully.

Any suggetion how to do it automatically?

Comment: Which language are you using? Most likely, a parser (ie `BeautifulSoup` or `DOMDocument`)  is what you're looking for.

Comment: Jan, I do it without programming language. I use this smal programm: http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=findandreplace&DownloadId=851369&FileTime=130458305187130000&Build=21050. It can find and replace all recurcively files in folder. I also know java and php languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could*  (note my comment that you shouldn't) use:

```
(?s:                   # parenthesis, turning on dotall mode
    <ins               # <ins literally
    (?:(?!</ins>).)*?  # anything else lazily afterwards
                       # making sure not to overrun </ins>
    "adsbygoogle"      # adsbygoogle
    .*?                # rest
    </ins>             # closing tag
)
```

Remove these matches completely, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/R6Oese/2).

Comment: I tried your regex, it works on your demo, but not work in Notepadd++, or "FindAndReplaceTool".

Comment: I tried again. It works. Thank your very much. You saved my time.